# How to convert a Vagrant box to a Docker image

Tags: image, docker, vagrant, provisioning

I saw that it's possible to convert a Docker image into a Vagrant box.

Is there a way to convert a Vagrant box into a Docker image?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I replayed this with EC2 boxes and Virtualbox boxes in my Github project [blacklabelops/centos](https://github.com/blacklabelops/centos). I have prepared a Vagrantfile with the necessary installation and you can try it yourself with your Vagrant boxes.

EC2 boxes:

- Create and provision an AMI image with https://github.com/katzj/ami-creator - Skripts in my repository.
- Afterwards use Guestfish in order to extract the image into a tarball. - Skripts in my repository.
- Import the tarball inside Docker. - Example in my repository.

And now with Vagrant Virtualbox, commands can be replayed with my provided Vagrantfile. Just clone the repository, spin it up and type:

```
$ qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw MyTry-disk1.vmdk mytry.img
```

> The Vagrant box's VMDK can be found in the Virtualbox folder, usually ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/.

After the raw has been created you can apply Guestfish.

```
$ guestfish -a mytry.img --ro
$ ><fs> run
```

> Note: tty

```
$ ><fs> list-filesystems 
/dev/sda1: ext4
/dev/VolGroup/lv_root: ext4
/dev/VolGroup/lv_swap: swap
$ ><fs> mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_root /
$ ><fs> tar-out / - | xz --best >>  mytry.xz
$ ><fs> exit
```

> Note: exiting tty

Importing into docker:

```
$ cat mytry.xz | docker import - mytryimage
```

Look inside the container

```
$ docker run -it mytryimage bash
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Greetings to Munich. Note: *guestfish* needs root priviledges.