# Move Vagrant guest disk to another provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, virtualbox

I used vagrant to create a virtualbox guest on my Mac based on ubuntu/trusty64. Is it possible to copy the virtualbox disk file to a cloud host such as AWS and boot it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Virtualbox image into a raw img which should be able to run on AWS. I have described the procedure here: [How to convert a Vagrant box to a Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321076/convert-vagrant-box-to-docker-image/31329813#31329813)

Just stop at the point where the img is created! You will have to take my tutorial for img creation because other tutorials use Virtualbox vdi files to create an image. Virtualbox does not provide/support vdi files anymore. Follow this tutorial on how to get the img in AWS running: https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/09/24/converting-a-virtualbox-vm-to-an-ec2-ami/

Also note the Vagrant AWS provider:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws

My proposed way is using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) or [AMI-Creator](https://github.com/blacklabelops/centos) for creating AMI-AWS cloud images and provision them with the Vagrant AWS provider. These boxes will be smaller and produce less problems than a converted Virtualbox box.