# How to convert VM image to dockerfile?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox

For work purpose, I have an ova file which I need to convert it to DockerFile.

Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to tar the whole file system and create a docker image from it using `FROM scratch` and `CMD /sbin/init` in your Dockerfile. This might work, but I guess you're more likely to fail. Docker is not meant to be used that way. Good luck!

Comment: Hope, the below link can be helpful to you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321076/how-to-convert-a-vagrant-box-to-a-docker-image

Comment: stumbled upon [a similar exercise](https://www.vinnie.work/blog/2021-03-19-virtualmachine-to-docker)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to do this.  They all involve getting at the disk image of the VM.  One is to mount the VDI, then create Docker image from that (see other Stackoverflow answers).  Another is to boot the VM and copy the complete disk contents, starting at root, to a shared folder.  And so on.  We have succeeded with multiple approaches.  As long as the disk in the VM is compatible with the kernel underlying the running container, creating Docker image that has the complete VM disk has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use a VM image and run it in a container. Many our customers have been using this project successfully: https://github.com/rancher/vm.git.

> RancherVM allows you to create VMs that run inside of Kubernetes pods,
>   called VM Pods. A VM pod looks and feels like a regular pod. Inside of
>   each VM pod, however, is a container running a virtual machine
>   instance. You can package any QEMU/KVM image as a Docker image,
>   distribute it using any Docker registry such as DockerHub, and run it
>   on RancherVM.

Recently this project has been made compatible for kubernetes as well. For more information: https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-04-27-ranchervm-now-available-on-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Install ShutIt as root:

```
sudo su -
(apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip git docker) || (yum update && yum install -y python-pip git docker which)
pip install shutit
```

The pre-requisites are python-pip, git and docker. The exact names of these in your package manager may vary slightly (eg docker-io or docker.io) depending on your distro.

You may need to make sure the docker server is running too, eg with ‘systemctl start docker’ or ‘service docker start’.

### Step 2

Check out the copyserver script:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/ianmiell/shutit_copyserver.git
```

### Step 3

Run the copy_server script:

```sh
cd shutit_copyserver/bin
./copy_server.sh
```

There are a couple of prompts – one to correct perms on a config file, and another to ask what docker base image you want to use. Make sure you use one as close to the original server as possible.

Note that this requires a version of docker that has the ‘docker exec’ option.

### Step 4

Run the build server:

```sh
docker run -ti copyserver /bin/bash
```

You are now in a practical facsimile of your server within a docker container!

#### Source

https://zwischenzugs.com/2015/05/24/convert-any-server-to-a-docker-container/